# Send entire rows in individual separate emails to different email recipiants

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop, office365

I have a full list of data, I need to go through each line of data and send the full row of data in an email to each person individually providing their statistics.

The email is in column A which will be used in the outlook .TO bit and the TM email will be used in the CC.

Data:
[Data Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrrkR.png)

I managed to find some things online and got this far:
which faults at the .body line

```
Sub test2()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Cells
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then
            With OutMail
                .To = Cells(cell.row, "A").Value
                .CC = Cells(cell.row, "B").Value
                .Subject = ""
                .Body = Cells(cell.row, "C:O")
                .Display
            End With
            Cells(cell.row, "P").Value = "sent"
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    Set OutApp = Nothing                       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I then realised you cannot put a full row of data into an email and began looking at using the RangeToHTML option. However even doing this my issue is now the headers and the row of data doesn't match up as they have to be taken separately:
[Email when ran using RangeToHTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sq23z.png)

What would be the best way to go about this?
Is it better to write the code to filter the table of data and copying the RangeToHTML into the email so it keeps the range as one to include the headings properly? If so how would i loop through each filter for the name? The names change on each set of data, and there can be over 100 rows.

Any suggestions on the best way about this would be great. Im not great with using loops or For Each, im quite new to this part of it.

Thanks in advance for all for your help.

Comment: I use a "Email_Temp" worksheet, where the 1st row will be the header row, and below you paste only your relevant row(s) of data. Then you copy the entire Table from "Email_Temp" worksheet and paste in the Email Body with `RangetoHTML`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to send each row of data with their respective headers in an email, you can consider combining the headers and data rows into a temporary Excel range and then converting this range to HTML.

Try this:

```
Sub SendEmailsWithData()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim TempWs As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    ' Create a temporary worksheet
    Set TempWs = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    ' Copy headers
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:O1").Copy TempWs.Range("A1")

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A").Cells
        If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

            ' Copy data row below the headers in the temporary worksheet
            Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(cell.Row).Columns("C:O").Copy TempWs.Rows(2)

            ' Create email
            Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
            With OutMail
                .To = cell.Value
                .CC = Cells(cell.Row, "B").Value
                .Subject = ""
                .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(TempWs.Range("A1:M2"))
                .Display
            End With

            Cells(cell.Row, "P").Value = "sent"
            Set OutMail = Nothing
        End If
    Next cell

    ' Delete temporary worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TempWs.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Set OutApp = Nothing                       
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Function to convert range to HTML
    Dim ClipBoard As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    Set ClipBoard = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    ClipBoard.body.innerHTML = CreateObject("shell.application").Namespace(TempFile).self.getdetailsof(0)
    
    TempWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Kill TempFile
    Set TempWB = Nothing

    RangetoHTML = ClipBoard.body.innerHTML
    Set ClipBoard = Nothing
End Function
```

This code creates a temporary worksheet, copies headers to it, and then iteratively adds each data row below the headers. It then sends an email with the combined data in HTML format and continues for the next row. After all rows are processed, the temporary worksheet is deleted.

Comment: This seems to exactly what i need and a great idea but it doesnt seem to work :(

I get an error on the line in the HTML code:
    ClipBoard.Body.innerHTML = CreateObject("shell.application").Namespace(TempFile).self.getdetailsof(0)

And the first temp file seems to copy over the headings twice, is there a way to start it from row 2 instead of it starting from row 1 and what edits do i need on the HTML row?

Comment: I have managed to get it all working by playing with some of the code ! Thanks so much !

Answer (score 0):

To get the content for the body use this:

```vb
Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin(vbTab, False, Cells(cell.Row, 3).Resize(, 13))
```

- `Cells(cell.Row, 3).Resize(,13)` returns the range you want
- `TextJoin` combines all cell values with a tab.

`.Body = Cells(cell.row, "C:O")`
throws an error due to two reasons:

- Cells expects one column instead of "C:O" a column range
- a range of cells can't return a value

Comment: This is really useful, but it doesn't fix the issue I have with the headers not being able to be put with it. It also doesn't keep the text formatting for the number formats etc. thank you though I appreciate your assistance!